# TypeScript - use types to construct values?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type Chocolate = {
    'flavour': 'Chocolate',
    'calories': 120
}
type Vanilla = {
    'flavour': 'Vanilla',
    'calories': 90
}
type Mango = {
    'flavour': 'Mango',
    'calories': 110
}
type Mint = {
    'flavour': 'Mint',
    'calories': 100
}


type UseCase = Chocolate | Vanilla | Mango | Mint;


export const chocolate: Chocolate = {
    'flavour': 'Chocolate',
    'calories': 120
}
export const vanilla: Vanilla = {
    'flavour': 'Vanilla',
    'calories': 90
}
export const mint: Mint = {
    'flavour': 'Mint',
    'calories': 100
}
export const mango: Mango = {
    'flavour': 'Mango',
    'calories': 110
}
```

And it seems pretty verbose..
Is there a way i could use the types as values (or vice versa) since they're the same?

Important note:
All of the values are hardcoded (i.e you can't have a value for "calories" which isn't 90/100/110/120), so it can't be just a `number`.

Comment: You probably should have something like `type UseCase = { flavour: string; calories: number }` instead of explicit types for each one.

Comment: Short answer, no you can't. But have you considered using a class with static members? Or an enum would be the same behaviour..

Comment: What are the types _for_?

Comment: @OtaconKiko Well, you can create types from values in many cases.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes he want's to create values from types though.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes - in my case, all of the values are hardcoded (i.e you can't have a value for "calories" which isn't 90/100/110/120), so it can't be just a `number`. (i'll update my question)

Comment: Am I missing something or is this just a place for `typeof`? https://tsplay.dev/NdvY6W

Comment: @OtaconKiko "(or vice versa)"

Comment: Create the values first, with `as const`, and then create a type from them using `typeof` (as also suggested by pink).

Comment: @DarrylNoakes missed the "or vice versa" then yes, the typeof is the way to go!

Comment: Or https://tsplay.dev/NrQ4zw

Comment: Or, my preferred method (keep it as an object): https://tsplay.dev/N9OPMW. The individual types are accessed by flavour key. Of course, you could also destructure the object before exporting it; the types don't care.

Comment: Correction to that playground: the mapped type is completely unnecessary in this case. `export type Flavors = typeof flavors` is all that is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to have the string and number literals inferred as literal types:

```
export const vanilla = {
    flavour: "Vanilla",
    calories: 90,
} as const;
```

Then you can use the [typeof operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator) to get the type:

```
export type Vanilla = typeof vanilla;
```

However, using `as const` for all your flavors may get a little repetitive. I suggest putting them all in a single object and then using `as const` for that one object instead:

```
const flavors = {
    chocolate: {
        flavour: "Chocolate",
        calories: 120,
    },
    vanilla: {
        flavour: "Vanilla",
        calories: 90,
    },
    mint: {
        flavour: "Mint",
        calories: 100,
    },
    mango: {
        flavour: "Mango",
        calories: 110,
    },
} as const;
```

Your flavor types can then be extracted in a similar manner using `typeof`:

```
type Chocolate = typeof flavors.chocolate;
type Vanilla = typeof flavors.vanilla;
type Mango = typeof flavors.mango;
type Mint = typeof flavors.mint;
type UseCase = Chocolate | Vanilla | Mango | Mint;
```

If you need to get all flavors, no matter the key, you can use

```
type UseCase = typeof flavors[keyof typeof flavors]; // same result as above
```

Finally, to get the original exports you had, you can destructure the `flavors` object:

```
export const { chocolate, vanilla, mint, mango } = flavors;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgewMYIDYENjQLxVJBAMykIwDcEAnAZwDolEUMsBuAKH2gDV0A7AS1QYouTkRLkqdMn0EZ2nKAFk+AcwQi84CONLoKNWgFs1CBduX9ewTWOJ6DdI1eDnIUAKrUIMdN9vaupI0ANoA1hAg4nYS+lIAuuxsKLzUNg5SmgDebFB5UAzIaJgQAFxQOflVsRQArpTlAETwRcwQjQA0udV5SOioVPwQ1OUAjABMAAxdVQC+M-kyAkLo5ZU9NQj1TTzLGJ3dPX0DlEMjUACc04dQ8zfO1ms3VRnbUI1KLgcbBf2Dw2NJtc5gs8iZeOonj9Xg13ioIQhvhtjv9zqNRsD8ndZlA-AUEKlXGw2BAAB5gKg2FJpCoFRjFLAdKBLOToJkPYDs0y3TQZGgsIA)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for something like this

```
type FlavoursMap = {
    Chocolate: 120,
    Vanilla: 90
}

type FlavourName = keyof FlavoursMap;


type UseCase<N extends FlavourName> = {
    flavour: N,
    calories: FlavoursMap[N],
}

const doSomeThing = <N extends FlavourName>(useCase: UseCase<N>) => {}

doSomeThing ({flavour: 'Chocolate', calories: 120})
```